# Page not found (404) Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/signup

Tags: python, django, postgresql, url, django-views

I am getting page not found 404 ERROR, in Django. Even though i have mapped the URL correctly both in the main app and this app.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.mainpage,name='main'),
    path("signup/",views.signup,name='signup'),
    path("login/",views.login,name='login'),
    path("logout/",views.logout,name='logout')
]
```

Now the below **url** is of the main app where I have included the **urls.py** of sub-app which is accounts.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('trial.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),   
]
```

This is the URL mapping of the app name accounts, used to handle the account and registration details.

The error is in this path

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/signup
```

Where as it works finely up to the below mentioned path.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup
```

Can anyone suggest me or help me finding out where it going wrong.
What it should happen is,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup
```

after this path when we click submit it should create a user in database and return or redirect the page to login page, with a message user created.

Below is the code of **views.py** of the accounts app.

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            firstname=first_name, lastname=last_name, username=username, email=email, password=password1)
        user.save()
        print("USER CREATED SUCCESSFULLY")
        return redirect('/login.html')
```

Anyone help me out what is going wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/signup` why two trailing `/signup`.
You have only made the link to just one.

Comment: @asdasd that's what am not getting, i have linked only once the signup page, as per my expectation it should jump to login.html as soon as user is created. What went wrong?

Comment: you can redirect the user to the login page like this: `return redirect('\login')`. Also can you share the template where you have created the registration form? because I think you have set the wrong form action in your template.

Comment: @AjayLingayat      I am not able to add it here, it is showing characters long by 200 letters, so how can i show you?

Comment: @AjayLingayat  Or is there problem with my database? should i have to write any query ? like makemigrations?

Comment: i don't think it is because of database. What value did you set for the `action` attribute in the form? So that I can tell  you the correct url path to submit the form.

Comment: @AjayLingayat  for action I had set ```signup``` . Here is my code for that ```<form action="signup" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}``` . **I am not able to display it in correct format sorry**

Comment: could you show your templates? `is it redirected to it after you try to signup `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/signup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

**signup.html**

```
<form action="\accounts\signup\" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: ```RuntimeError at /accounts/signup
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.```

Comment: A runtime error is coming. And after showing this error i edited it to forward slash like ```/accounts/signup``` then also same error, If i change it to ```accounts/signup``` page not found error.

Comment: i have edited the answer . See the new `action` attribute value it has one more slash after `\accounts\signup`. Try it.

Comment: Bingo man, thank you so much. I am trying this from past week.

Comment: Can you have a look at my another question in my profile, like the submit button is not working, I am using ajax, JS, html , to validate some answers.